# How do I create an advancement that detect for an entity?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I create advancement that trigger when player gets near this:

```
execute at @e[type=minecraft:item_frame,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:nether_star"},Facing:1b}] if block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:netherite_block if block ~ ~-2 ~ minecraft:diamond_block if block ~1 ~-2 ~ minecraft:quartz_block if block ~-1 ~-2 ~ minecraft:quartz_block if block ~ ~-2 ~1 minecraft:quartz_block if block ~ ~-2 ~-1 minecraft:quartz_block run
```

I tried testing but I don't really understand a lot about them.